# react-jsx-parser in React native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to convert string to jsx in react native -

```
import React from 'react';
import JsxParser from 'react-jsx-parser';

const strJSX = `<Text>Hello World!</Text>`;
const App = () => {
  return <JsxParser jsx={strJSX} />;
};
```

I am getting the below error -

[image]

If react-jsx-parser works in react native?

Comment: Why would you want to use a jsx parser in the first place ?

Comment: Need a jsx parser for react-native, so trying out this package.